# Relationship between nodes in wavefunction and orthogonality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space

I read that if I want to construct a wavefunction orthogonal to given $n$ orthogonal wavefunctions, then the new wavefunction should have $n$ nodes. Is this valid under all conditions? Is there a mathematical theorem which says so?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense without more context, since wavefunctions don't need to have nodes at all.

Comment: Can you give an example where an excited state doesn't have a node at all? For ex.,first excited state has one node - it needs to be orthogonal to one state - and second excited state has two nodes and so on. My above statement is a generalization of that.

Comment: For example, the wavefunctions of [coherent states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states) don't have any nodes, they are just Gaussians.

Comment: Suppose I have two Gaussians in the same region, how will I make them orthogonal? When I integrate, things just add up.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Gaussians are not orthogonal. If you want to orthogonalise them you will indeed need to introduce nodes.

Comment: Is it possible you are formulating the question in a slightly sloppy manner? Take a look at this: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/pbox.html#c1. All these wave functions are of course orthogonal. For n=1, no nodes, for n=2, one node, for $n=i, i-1$ nodes. May this be what you're referring to?

Comment: It's worth considering that for periodic boundary conditions on $[0,2\pi]$, $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are orthogonal for kernel $1$ and exhibit the same number of nodes (2). This same situation shows up in the spherical harmonics.

Comment: For that matter, on open boundary conditions any even function is orthogonal to any odd function on kernel $1$, and you can have any relationship between the number of node the two exhibit that you want.

Comment: You might be getting at [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) in combination with [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. For an example, take as given these eigenfunctions of the infinite square well:
$$
\psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac 2L}\sin(n\pi x/L),\quad x\in[0,L],\quad n=2,3,4,\ldots,N.
$$
If you want to construct a function which is orthogonal to them, you can choose $\psi_1$, which has zero nodes. Or $\psi_{N+1}$, which has $N$ nodes. Or $\psi_{N+1001}$, which has $N+1000$ nodes.

However, it is true that the eigenfunctions of a well-behaved single-particle hamiltonian, **when ordered by energy**, have an increasing number of nodes. (Moreover, you can prove that the nodes interweave, i.e. there's a zero of $\psi_{n+1}$ between any two zeros of $\psi_n$.) This follows from the theorems of [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory), which is well treated in most serious differential equations textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of the eigenfunctions of Sturm-Liouville equations; [here's a description w/o a proof](http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/mat463/ODEBook/Book/SL.pdf); the Schrodinger equation is of this type.